# How to convert FlutterStandardTypedData to NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, flutter

I have an app written in dart which uses a channel to call a method in Objective-C. The method needs data in form of an NSArray to act. I am passing this data as Uint8List from dart but in Objective-C, it shows that it's a FlutterStandardTypedData. Is there any way to convert that to an NSArray? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to copy it out of the `FlutterStandardTypedData` using something like... (Note that in this example the typed data is doubles - you presumably have bytes)

```
  if let args = call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
    let au = args["data"] as? FlutterStandardTypedData {
    
    au.data.withUnsafeBytes{(pointer: UnsafeRawBufferPointer) in
      let doubles = pointer.bindMemory(to: Double.self)
      for index in 0..<Int(au.elementCount) {
        // copy to the NSArray
      }
    }
    result(nil)
  } else {
    result(FlutterError.init(code: "errorProcess", message: "data or format error", details: nil))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues w/ FlutterStandardTypedData as well.  From what i'm reading this should be serialized "auto-magically" on the iOS side as it's a supported data type.  I can see on my end, for instance, that the length of the byte buffer is the value i'm expecting.  My issue is I cannot seem to access a single value of the byte data in the same method i can see the length value.  "Unrecognized selector for FlutterStandardTypedData" whenever i try to access it like an array...I cannot find good documentation either.  If i use a simple data type, like string, things work out just fine.  I'm only getting burned by the more complex data type(s)...

I figured it out, in the plugin you have to use FlutterStandardTypedData as the data type for the array, and then you can see the .data elements on the native iOS side.  Without this data type, coming in to the iOS side i could "see" the data but would get memory exceptions every time i would try to access the data(objects/elements) in the list.  Xcode was previously converting my NSArray to a FlutterStandardTypedData in the IDE (even though i specified NSArray NOT FlutterStandard...) auto-magically, but again, erroring out whenever i would try to work w/ the object.  Simply changing from NSArray in plugin to FlutterStandardTypedData  solved my problem, just took a while to figure out b/c the documentation wasn't very clear (that i came across).